# Need help setting up HAProxy with two backends

Tags: haproxy

I'm very unfamiliar with HAProxy, but I'm trying to set it up to proxy different backend targets based on the hostname. For example, if someone tries to access https://managementserver.domain.com for systems management and also https://packages.domain.com for the package repository, they could be connected to the appropriate resource on the back end.

My haproxy.cfg looks something like this:

```
global
  maxconn 10000
  log *:514  local0

defaults
  mode http
  timeout connect 5000ms
  timeout client 50000ms
  timeout server 50000ms
  log global
  option httplog

frontend domain.com
  bind *:443 ssl force-tlsv12 crt /etc/pki/tls/wildcard.domain.com.pem 

  acl host_manage hdr(host) -i managementserver.domain.com
  acl host_packages hdr(host) -i packages.domain.com

  use_backend mgmt_svr if host_manage
  use_backend packages_svr if host_packages

  default_backend mgmt_svr

backend mgmt_svr
  server management systems.domain.com:443 ssl verify none

backend packages_svr
  server packages repo.domain.com:443 check ssl verify none
```

In practice, access to the management server seems to be working, but when trying to access the package repo, I get 404 errors on the client. I have tried pointing the client directly to the package repo and it works as expected. So, it has to be something about how I have the HAProxy set up, but I'm not familiar enough with HAProxy to know what I'm doing wrong.

If it makes a difference, the package repo is running in NexusPro. We have some custom RPM's in a yum repo there. The specific error when trying to access the repo is:

```
https://packages.domain.com/repository/custom-rpms/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
```

Any help or advice would be appreciated as much of the documentation seems to be written for people who already understand a lot more about this than I do.

Comment: Check your logs.

Comment: The logs haven't really given me any idea what is happening or what I am doing wrong. It shows  no errors.

Comment: **What is in the logs?**

Comment: All I get is entries like this:

Feb 25 11:42:37 localhost.localdomain haproxy[10438]: 192.168.53.199:53646 [25/Feb/2021:11:42:36.829] domain.com~ packages_svr/packages 43/0/90/45/178 404 214 - - ---- 1/1/0/1/0 0/0 "GET /repository/custom-rpms/repodata/repomd.xml HTTP/1.1"

Comment: Now find the corresponding log entries from your backend server.

Comment: Ok...had to wait for access log to show up. Looks like it may be passing through the hostname URL from the front-side of the proxy. Instead of showing "repo.domain.com" it's seeing packages.domain.com. 

I'm assuming this is some issue wtih how I've got HAProxy configured. Somehow, I need to hit the backend server using the correct hostname. Not sure how to do that.

Comment: So you want to _change_ the hostname as the request goes through? You gave an example HTTP request using `packages.domain.com`. If the backend expects `repo.domain.com` then that would explain the 404. But that's trivial to fix on the backend server, no changes required or expected in haproxy.

Comment: I guess I'm even more lost now. You're saying I don't have to change my HAProxy configuration? What would I change, then?

Comment: Again, you change the configuration of the web server so that it responds to the hostnames you want.

Comment: It's a load balancer in front of a NexusPro server. I don't believe I have access to that.

Comment: It's probably time to have a chat with whoever does run that server about what the hostname is supposed to be.

Comment: That did it. The admin for NexusPro updated a listener rule on the ALB to allow traffic through with that hostname. Default rule was 404, so that makes sense. Thanks for the help.